# Making several wordclouds out of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ipython, word-cloud

I have a list of dictionaries in `union_dicts`. To give you an idea it's structured as follows

```
union_dicts = [{'bla' : 6, 'blub': 9}, {'lub': 20, 'pul':12}]
```

(The actual lists of dicts is many times longer, but this is to give the idea)

For this particular list of dictionaries I want to make a wordcloud. The function that makes a wordcloud is as follows (nothing wrong with this one):

```
def make_words(words):
    return ' '.join([('<font size="%d">%s</font>'%(min(1+words[x]*5/max(words.values()), 5), x)) for x  in words])
```

Now I have written the following code that should give every dictionary back. Return gives only the first dictionary back in the following function below:

```
def bupol():
    for element in union_dicts: 
        return HTML(make_words(element))
bupol()
```

I have already tried to simply print it out, but then I simply get ''Ipython display object'' and not the actual display. I do want the display. Yield also doesn't work on this function and for some reason using `list = []` along with `list.apped()` return list instead of returning in the current way also doesn't work. I'm quite clueless as how to properly iterate over this so I get a display of every single dictionary inside `union_dicts` which is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
def bupol():
    result = []
    for element in union_dicts: 
        result.append(HTML(make_words(element)))
    return result
```